# Cancel scipy.optimize.root from inside

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I need to solve a system of equations in `(x, y)`. Where both are multi-dimensional.

I can split up the system of equations into

```
guess x
    given x, solve y such that subset of equations hold
given y, compute remainder of equations and find error in x
update x
```

So I've set it up as a nested `optimize.root()`. *Almost always* I can find a `y` for a given `x`. Therefore, this is much faster since I'm reducing dimensionality by a lot.

However, sometimes there exists no such `y`. And that becomes pretty clear inside the error function that computes `y`. However, as I've given the inner solver a large `maxiter`, the inner solver is wasting a lot of time until it gives up (and then I can return a large error manually to inform the outer solver that `x` was a bad guess. What is the best way to "force the hand" of the solver to give up?

Comment: Maybe use `.root()` twice, first with small `maxiter` and then (if progress looks good) with a larger one? Otherwise, all you can do is to play with termination conditions, which are solver-specific (can be found in the [docs  for each solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html))

Answer (score 0):

How about raising an error inside the cost function?